# Why does Nikon D3100 makes occasionallly noise and viewfinder shifts when pressing shutter button

Tags: lens, viewfinder, shutter-release, sound

A Nikon D3100 occasional makes a quiet *ka-chunk* noise occasionally, when pressing the shutter button.

Also, when re-seating the lens or powering the camera up, it will do the same thing 4-5 times in that first second.

When it does this, looking through the viewfinder, the image shifts a little. It seems like it might shift diagonally. It almost reminds me of when you turn on a LCD monitor on a PC and they would automatically adjust the centering of the image, if you've ever seen that happen.

I've seen people say that this sort of thing [happens with a D90](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/why-does-nikon-d90-makes-strange-sound-and-shifts-mirror-in-viewfinded-eyepiece) but this is a D3100 with VR turned off on the lens.

FYI: It's my daughters camera, and I don't use it, but she's saying that she's just noticed it doing this.

Comment: Try disabling stabilization on the lens to see if that is the source. It's the only thing than can shift your view through the OVF.

Answer (score 2):

It is the VR in the lens. Even if you have it turned off, when power is first supplied to the lens it will center the stabilizing element. If the camera is allowed to go into stand-by mode and then awakened by pressing the shutter button the same thing can occur if the stabilizing element in the lens has moved.